# I need to split values in a column into its own column with the text relating to it underneath in SQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table below that is output all the field names in one row with the text next to it:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wd9Z9.png)

but i need to look like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdsdH.png)

Any help would be appreciated.

I have tried a few different ways to get the data to look like the above with no joy.

Comment: Please post code, data, and results as text, not screenshots. http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: Search for conditional aggregation and/or  mysql pivot.